# HTML: позволить пользователю менять ширину столбцов в таблице

Tags: html, html5

Добрый день.

Имеется таблица (тэг table), количество записей и столбцов неизвестны. Хотелось бы сделать функционал, который разрешит пользователю самостоятельно менять ширину любого столбца с автоматическим изменением ширины оставшихся, аналогично как это делается в MS Excel или других электронных таблицах (навёл курсор на границу столбца, нажал кнопку мыши, потащил, отпустил - ширина изменилась).

Предположим, что имеется HTML5. Excel не установлен.

Comment: jquery-плагин [colResizable](http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/)

Comment: А если таблица сгенерирована в DOM, например, тем же jQuery, будет работать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <style type="text/css">
 td
 { 
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
 }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
 
    $('td').resizable({
        alsoResize: "#astor img",
  minWidth:100,
  minHeight: 50
    });
 
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <table border="1" >
 <tr><td>Текст</td><td>Текст</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Текст</td><td>Текст</td></tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Приблизительно так, если на Jquery ui
http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B

Comment: Есть одна особенность:  раздвигается конкретная ячейка а не строка или колонка.

Comment: в итоге взял за основу этот вариант, colResizable как-то странно вёл себя (у меня таблица гораздо более сложная, чем в примере). Хотя да, можно получить странный эффект, когда раздвигается только одна ячейка, а не колонка целиком. Ещё вопрос - как запретить изменение ширины по вертикали?

Comment: и ещё, если на таблице в 240 строк запустить эту функцию для "td", всё начинает заметно тормозить.